# Design DFA that checks wheter a boolean formula is true or false

Tags: function, automata, dfa, deterministic

I really need some help guys, I made like 100 examples of constucting DFA's and I'm stuck with this one. Any help will be much appreciated.

So I have some random boolean function, for example:
f(a,b,c,d) = (a∨c)∧((a∧b)∨(c ↔ d)) and I should make a DFA which accepts all of the strings which are true {3,7,8,11,12,13,14,15 in binary) everything else should be rejected. So basicly I need a DFA who converts these integers into binary form and accepts them, rejecting the other integers left. How I make that? I spent hours trying to quess the states.. How you make a transition table in this case?

Once again, thank you for helping me ! :)

Comment: So the formula to evaluate is fixed, exactly the one in the question? The input of the DFA would be 4 boolean values?

Comment: yes the formula is fixed, and the input would be exactly 4 values, everything else after that is ignored

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, the problem is 'relatively easy' in the sense that the input is of fixed size, which means that the accepted language is also finite. I will give a sketch of the construction, which will result in a relatively large number of states but does not use a compilcated idea.

Examine the formula with a truth value table. There are `4` variables to be evaluated, which means that there are `2^4 = 16` possible inputs.

Arrange these inputs in a decision tree consisting out of `16` paths from the root (which is the initial state of the DFA) to `16` leaves. A leaf is a terminal state if and only if the path leading to it corresponds to an input which evaluates to yes in the truth value table.

Note that it is always possible for a finite language to be recognized by a DFA - construct a NDFA which accepts every single word in the language and convert this one to a DFA (which can be complex in detail, but such an automaton is guaranteed to exist by [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/ndfa_to_dfa_conversion.htm) construction).

Comment: Thank you sir. The problem is that this is an exam task, that means you have like 5-6 mins for it, and Im pretty sure I wont make decision tree with 256 paths , construct NFA and convert it to DFA.. :D The idea is nice, I just wonder how can I make simple DFA which accepts the numbers 3,7,8,11,12,13,14,15 in binary ofc, and rejects the others left which are 0,1,2,4,5,6,9,10.

Comment: Do you believe there is a pattern in the numbers to accept and reject that permits a less lengthy solution? Explicitly writing down all the paths is indeed a bit lengthy. However, I somehow miscounted the number of possible inputs; the actual number is smaller.

Comment: @stenil : if the above post was useful , please accept and upvote. Respect each reply you receive because they requires much time and effort.